# PyZMQ CURVE auth user credentials

Tags: authentication, zeromq, curve, pyzmq, zeromq-auth

Is it possible to retrieve some user related data from auth context during CURVE authorization? I.e., I configure auth the following way:

```
rpc_server = zmq.Context.instance().socket(zmq.REP)
rpc_server.curve_secretkey = server_secret
rpc_server.curve_publickey = server_public
rpc_server.curve_server = True  # must come before bind
rpc_server.bind(rpc_endpoint)

rpc_stream = zmqstream.ZMQStream(rpc_server)
rpc_stream.on_recv_stream(self.echo)
```

Is it possible to get certificate data inside self.echo()? The goal is to avoid passing identity by REQ clients explicitly. Probably it isn't a good practice, any suggestions are appreciated.